# Selective dim screens

Tags: xorg, monitors, multi-monitor

How can I dim only select screens of my multiple-monitor linux system?

I have 5 monitors connected to my computer 4 *15 inch and one 27 inch.
sometimes i want to use only the main screen (27) and have the rest black or in power save
How can i do this? I'm running ubuntu linux 13.10 with kde.
To blackout all screens I use `xset dpms force off` but this will be undone as soon as i touch the mouse or keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-display :HOST:DISPLAY` to chose display to apply dpms setting like this:

```
xset -display :0 dpms force off
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. i have been trying but get a 'xset:  unable to open display ":0:0"' response,

Comment: sorry the format is `-display host:dpi`, same as $DISPLAY value, so `-display :0`, `-display :1` etc. should work.

Comment: `-display :0` turns of all screens and `-display :1` gives a `unable to open display ":1"` error message , as i understand :0 indicates the host in this case the whole X11 display system.